# What is the correct way to prove that for all $m \in Z$, if $m$ is even then then $mn$ is even?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

As the title says, prove:

$m \in Z$, if $m$ is even then then $mn$ is even

My attempt:

By definition of an even number, $2i$, and definition of an odd number, $2j+1$ I did the following by cases. I thought it was logical to create cases for if $n$ was even or if it was odd.

Case 1: Even

$$mn=(2i)(2j)$$

$$=4(ij)$$

Case 2: Odd

$$mn=(2i)(2j+1)$$
$$= (2i)(2j)+2i$$
$$=4(ij)+2i$$

However, after my attempt the books answer was the following:

"Suppose $x,y \in Z$ and $x$ is even. Then $x=2a$ for some integer a, by definition of an even number. Thus $xy = (2a)(y) = 2(ay).$ Therefore, $xy=2b$ where $b$ is the integer $ay$, so $xy$ is even. "

Are both methods acceptable? Any suggestions to the  way I did this are more then welcome!

Comment: I don't see any problems with the way you went about it. An integer $n$ can either be even or odd. Nothing else. Your books method simply took care of both cases with one argument

Comment: There is no need to consider cases. The book's version is better. In your case for odd numbers you performed an unnecessary multiplication and didn't finish the proof. All you needed was $mn=(2i)(2j+1)=2(i(2j+1))\implies mn$ is even.

Comment: Your proof is perfectly reasonable and acceptable and neither have any error.  The book is more efficient.  We don't actually care if $n = 2j+1$ or $2j$ or $5j^2 +27l$ we *can* do those cases and it will be correct.  But we don't *need* to do those cases.  It's enough to do $m = 2k$ and $n = n$ so $mn = 2k\times n = 2(k\times n)$ is even.  But we could do cases i)if $n=2j$ then $mn=4kj$ and ii) if $n = 2j+1$ then $mn=4kj + 2j$ and if $n=5j^2 +27l$ then $mn=10kj^2+54kl$. Nothing *wrong* with doing those.  We just don't have to.

Comment: Thank you for the comments!